# I don't understand this line of code tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

Tags: python

I see this line a lot these days: `tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)` and don't understand its purpose. My problem is not the `*args` and `**kwargs`).

For example in these lines of code here:

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

I know that the class `SampleApp` is going to inherit from `Tk`.

I have another question: the init method in the class Tk is prefered to not be accessed like that, true or not.

Comment: If you understand `*args` and `**kwargs`, then I have no idea what you *don't* understand. `tk.Tk.__init__(...)` is just a function call. Could you elaborate which part of the code you posted is confusing you? Do you know how classes work and what `__init__` is?

Comment: You can use `super().__init__` instead of `tk.Tk.__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor of the inherited class might take positional and keyword attributes. The inherating class passes those when calling the super constructor.

**Edit:** The constructor of [`tk.Tk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter.Tk) takes some named arguments.

Comment: What those parameters could be ? (give me some examples please)